# buscar y mostrar datos Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel-5

hola buenas a todos vengo a ustedes a que me puedan ayudar en una duda que tengo ye no puedo realizar ando realizando en laravel 5.8 un CRUD la desde ahi todo bien mi problema es que necesito buscar datos que tengo en mi tabla cliente y mostrarlo en un de vista empresa la cual tengo un Form que solo guardaría el id del cliente capturado junto con otros datos que tengo en un formulario

aca mis datos de mi tabla cliente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este es el formulario la cual tiene que hacer el trabajo de buscar y mostrar solo el nombre y el id del cliente la cual una ves capturado los datos solo tiene que mostrarlo en los campos Administrador o Responsable e ID, y guardar el ID del cliente junto con los demás datos menos el nombre que seria el campo Administrador o Responsable
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el codigo de mi vista con la cual estoy intentando hacer capturar los datos del cliente y enviarlos a mis campos indicados pero no puedo bueno ya intente muchas formas pero no logro hacer lo que quiero

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('title','Empresa')

@section('content')

    {!! Form::open(['route'=>'empresas.store', 'method' => 'POST', 'files' => 'true']) !!}

        {{-- Formulario de busqueda --}}
        <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 50px">
            {!! Form::open(['route'=>'clientes.index', 'method' => 'GET','class' => 'navbar-form navbar-lef pull-right','role' => 'Search']) !!}
            {!! Form::text('buscar', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Ingrese el DNI']) !!}
            {!! Form::submit('Buscar',['class' => 'btn btn-outline-success']) !!}

            {!! Form::close() !!}


            {{-- formulario de resgistro de empresa --}}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                {!! Form::label('name','Rason Social') !!}
                {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class'=> 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Rason Social ']) !!}
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                {!! Form::label('cif','CIF') !!}
                {!! Form::text('cif', null, ['class'=> 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Ingrese el CIF']) !!}
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    {!! Form::label('raponsable', 'Administrador o Rsponsable') !!}
                    {!! Form::text('responsable', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'ingrese Responsable']) !!}
                </div>
                <div class="col-1">
                    {!! Form::label('cliente_id', 'ID') !!}
                    {!! Form::text('id_cliente', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'ID']) !!}
                </div>
            </div>

        <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                {!! Form::label('mail','Mail') !!}
                {!! Form::text('mail', null, ['class'=> 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Ingrese el Mail ']) !!}
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                {!! Form::label('tfijo','Telefono Fijo') !!}
                {!! Form::text('tfijo', null, ['class'=> 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Ingrese Telefono Fijo']) !!}
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                {!! Form::label('tmovil','Telefono Movil') !!}
                {!! Form::text('tmovil', null, ['class'=> 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Ingrese el Telefono Molvil']) !!}
                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">


                <div class="col">
                {!! Form::label('ciudad','Ciudad') !!}
                {!! Form::text('ciudad', null, ['class'=> 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Ingrese la Ciudad']) !!}
                </div>

                <div class="col">
                {!! Form::label('provincia','Provincia') !!}
                {!! Form::text('provincia', null, ['class'=> 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Ingrese la Provincia']) !!}
                </div>

                <div class="col">
                {!! Form::label('localidad','Localidad') !!}
                {!! Form::text('localidad', null, ['class'=> 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Ingrese la Localidad']) !!}
                </div>

                <div class="col">
                {!! Form::label('direccion','Direccion') !!}
                {!! Form::text('direccion', null, ['class'=> 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Ingrese la Dirección']) !!}
                </div>
                <div class="col-1">
                    {!! Form::label('codpostal','Postal') !!}
                    {!! Form::text('codpostal', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => ' Postal']) !!}
                </div>
        </div>

        </div>

        {!! Form::submit('Guardar',['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
    {!! Form::close() !!}

@endsection
```

aca les muestro mi controlador cliente

```
<?php

namespace Energy\Http\Controllers;

use Energy\Cliente;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Energy\Http\Requests\StoreClienteRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class ClienteController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request  $request)
    {
        // $clientes = DB::table('clientes')->get();
        // dd($clientes);

        $clientes = Cliente::orderby('id','desc')->paginate(5);
       return view('clientes.index', compact('clientes'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
         return view('clientes.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(StoreClienteRequest $request)
    {
        $cliente = new Cliente();
        $clientes = Cliente::all();
        $cliente->name = $request->input('name');
        $cliente->dni = $request->input('dni');
        $cliente->mail = $request->input('mail');
        $cliente->tfijo = $request->input('tfijo');
        $cliente->tmovil = $request->input('tmovil');
        $cliente->direccion = $request->input('direccion');
        $cliente->localidad = $request->input('localidad');
        $cliente->provincia = $request->input('provincia');
        $cliente->codpostal = $request->input('codpostal');

        $cliente->save();
        return view('clientes.index', compact('clientes'));
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }
    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

y aca mi controlador empresa

```
<?php

namespace Energy\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class EmpresaController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('empresas.create');
    }
    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }
    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

y este es modelo cliente

```
<?php

namespace Energy;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Cliente extends Model
{
    //
    //
    public function  empresas()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Energy\Empresa'); //relacion 1 a muchos
    }

    public function scopeId($query, $dni)
    {   
        if ($dni !='') 
        {
            $query->where('dni','like','%$dni%');
        }
    }   
}
```

ahí sigo a ver si logro encontrar una solución ami problema y espero puedan ayudarme saludos

Comment: Hola, no entiendo la duda, serías tan amable en indicarnos además si obtienes algún error?

Comment: Más fácil podrías agregar el campo de búsqueda en tu página donde muestras tus clientes de modo general y que a cada cliente le pongas un botón para agregar los datos extras que requieres. Así cuando filtres a tus clientes desde la principal solo seleccionas al adecuado y no es necesario estar recargando a cada rato páginas. Otra opción que tienes es con ajax y datatables.

Comment: Hola aprendiz mi dura es que yo quiero buscar un cliente que tengo en tabla cliente y enviarlo a mi form solo el nombre y el id del cliente, por que luego en ese form se guardaran algunos datos mas el id del cliente ya tengo una tabla empresa que me pide el id del cliente esa es mi duda como podria hacer eso estaba intentando hacerlo de la manera que muestro arriba pero no me sale, y respecto a la que dices tu pagan estaba pensando hacerlo asi pero no se como empesar esta queriendo meter Vue js si tienes alguna info que me puedas pasar sobre ajax te lo agradeceria un monton